# Ionic with Firebase V.3 authentification

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently passed on firebase v3 for my app project, but my authentification system doesn't work and I don't understand why. Here is my code :

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.loginEmail = function(){
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
            });
        };
    })
    .controller('signinCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.signupEmail = function(){  
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
            });
        };
    });
```

and my form :

```
<form>
        <ion-list>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="enter username..." ng-model="data.username">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="you@domain.com" ng-model="data.email">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="At least 6 characters" ng-model="data.password">
            </label>
        </ion-list>
        <button class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="signupEmail()">Done</button>
    </form>
```

The Chrome console return me this message :

```
ReferenceError: email is not defined
```

Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize a variable email and store value from sign in form in it before pass it onto firebase database. Also give it an id so that element can be selected. Do the same for password too.

```js
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

```html
<form>
        <ion-list>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="enter username..." ng-model="data.username">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="you@domain.com" ng-model="data.email">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="At least 6 characters" ng-model="data.password">
            </label>
        </ion-list>
        <button class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="signupEmail()">Done</button>
    </form>
```

Now Call firebase to create the user.

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
            });
```

Comment: It's work ! there is still few errors but I'm work on it ! Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: this approach for initializing variables is completely wrong, you should not recommend this approach